# Value is added to end of database entry rather than updating the relevant column

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm currently working with MongoDB, Express and Angular and have run into a problem. When I try to update a columns data in the database, it is instead added at the end. Below is the code.

```
function addSupporters(candidate){
    Supporter.find({"name": "Susan Sullivan"},function(err,supporter){
        supporter.candidateName = candidate; 
    })
}
```

This code updates the `candidateName` to the person they support. It is called from the method below.

```
router.incrementUpvotes = function(req, res) {
    Candidate.findById(req.params.id, function(err,candidate) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);
        else {
            addSupporters(candidate.name);
            candidate.support += 1;
            candidate.save(function (err) {
                if (err)
                    res.send(err);
                else
                    res.json({ message: 'Candidate Upvoted!', data: candidate});
            });
        }
    });
}
```

The `incrementUpvotes` calls the `addSupporters(candidate.name)` when a person upvotes or "supports" them and adds the candidate name to the supporter.

The output I am getting is...

```
[
    {
        _id: 58189c8b3273e81568f0f918,
        name: 'Susan Sullivan',
        email: 'S.Sullivan@hotmail.com',
        candidateName: ''
    },
    candidateName: 'Susan Miller'
]
```

Comment: Are you using `node-mongodb-native` or `mongoose`?

Comment: I am using mongoose at the moment

Comment: it seems that your Supporter.find() method returns an array of supporters, therefore your function argument "supporter" is not a single object, but an array instead. Try supporter[0].candidateName = candidate;

Comment: Try [`findByIdAndUpdate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate). It will not explain why your current code doesn't work, but is the "designated" way to do what you are trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2nd argument seems to be an array

```
function addSupporters(candidate){
    Supporter.find({"name": "Susan Sullivan"},function(err,supporters){
        for (i = 0; i < supporters.length; i++) {
            supporters[i].candidateName = candidate; 
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't have the reputation to upvote anyone :/ but here is the answer that worked for me.

```
function addSupporters(candidate){
    Supporter.find({"name": "Susan Sullivan"},function(err,supporter){
        supporter[0].candidateName = candidate;
        supporter[0].save();
    });
}
```

Comment: notice you're updating only the first supporter matched by find function. Isn't possible to have several matching supporters?

Answer (score 0):

```
    router.incrementUpvotes = function(req, res) {
              var conditions = { id: req.params.id }
            , update = { $inc: { support : 1 }}
            , options = { multi: true };

            Candidate.update(conditions, update, options, function (err) {
              if (err)
                 res.send(err);
              else
                 res.json({ message: 'Candidate Upvoted!', data: candidate});
            });
    }
```

Hope this will help